# How do I handle nested foreach without overriding the entire fields with single value?

Tags: php

Please, I am trying to use **findBy** which returns an array of objects. As I can't use setter on the array, I looped through in order to get a way to use setId, etc. However, I have another which I want to use to modify where the id is found.
The problem I am encountering now is, while I tried to nest the **foreach**, it changes all the keys and values by one.
For example.

I have

```
id  = 49
key = "primary_school"
value = "University Primary School"

id = 49
key = "school_school"
value = "Baseline International School"

id = 49
key = "tertiary_school"
value = "University of India"
```

When I tried to modify with

```
id  = 49
key = "primary_school"
value = "University Primary School"

id = 49
key = "school_school"
value = "Kumasi Grammar School"

id = 49
key = "tertiary_school"
value = "University of Ghana"
```

instead to do that, it overrides the entire contents as follows:

```
id  = 49
key = "primary_school"
value = "University Primary School"

id = 49
key = "primary_school"
value = "University Primary School"

id = 49
key = "primary_school"
value = "University Primary School"
```

I don't know how to go about it so that I can have appropriate values.

```
$entityManager = $this->doctrine->getManager();
$em =  $this->em->getRepository(School::class);
        
$query = $em->findBy(['id' => $data['session']['id']]);
if ($query !== null) {
  foreach ($query as $q) {
    foreach($data['school'] as $key => $value) {
      $q->setId($data['session']['id']);
      $q->setKey($key);
      $q->setValue($value); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You loop through your $data['school'] in the record's loop, it will modify all values of query for each $data['school']. So you always get the result of the last loop for each results. You probably need some kind of condition before setting the data. I don't really get what you're trying to archieve so I can't say more

Comment: Yes, that is it. Instead to update with the inner foreach, it only update all with the last loop of foreach result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track

```
$entityManager = $this->doctrine->getManager();
$em =  $this->em->getRepository(School::class);
        
$query = $em->findBy(['id' => $data['session']['id']]);
   
    if($query !== null) {
        foreach($data['school'] as $key => $value) {
            foreach($query as $q) {
                if($q->getKey() === $key) {
                    $q->setValue($value);     
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

All you need do is to check if the keys of both array match to update the value wherever it's applicable. The illustration is cited above is very comprehensive enough. You are facing duplication and overriding of values. If values if what need to change, if you need keys, accommodate with if statement to check if the key match, otherwise include.

---

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I wonder why people don't understand it. I didn't put check on it. Thank you.